# Magento: Newsletter double opt-in also needed for registered customers

Tags: php, magento, newsletter

I have successfully setup the newsletter subscription for guests, so that if a guest signs up for the newsletter, he gets the newsletter confirmation request email where he has to click the confirmation link. This "double opt-in" is needed for every newsletter-signup by law here in Germany.

The problem is with customers who are already registered: they can subscribe in their account to the newsletter but here there is no double opt-in. So after checking subscribe they get immediately subscribed to the newsletter without getting the confirmation request email.

I have found only old tutorials on how to change this to double opt-in for registered customers, but these tutorials do not work anymore with my current version of Magento (1.5).

So how do I change the function "subscribe" in `app/code/core/Mage/Newsletter/Model/Subscriber.php` to get this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they have the same code (or at least very similar) as 1.6, then you should be able to comment out what is line 291 for me in `public function subscribe($email)`:

```
$isOwnSubscribes = ($customerSession->isLoggedIn() && $ownerId == $customerSession->getId());
```

And it will mark the subscription as "not active" rather than immediately "subscribed". For reference, here's that chunk of code:

```
// if user subscribes own login email - confirmation is not needed
$ownerId = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')
     ->setWebsiteId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getWebsiteId())
     ->loadByEmail($email)
     ->getId();
 $isOwnSubscribes = ($customerSession->isLoggedIn() && $ownerId == $customerSession->getId());
 if ($isOwnSubscribes == true){
      $this->setStatus(self::STATUS_SUBSCRIBED);
 }
 else {
      $this->setStatus(self::STATUS_NOT_ACTIVE);
 }
```

Right up above that it's setting the `$isOwnSubscribes` flag to `false`, so this will just let it remain false. You could also comment out the `$ownerId` loading as well, as it's only used in the part to check if the user is subscribing their own email.

Comment: no, unfortunately commenting out the line you suggested does not seem to work. am i doing something wrong here? after changing the code, i flush all caches and than the code-change should work, right? nevertheless, here is my current subscribe method: [link](https://gist.github.com/1264041)

Comment: Hmm, that looks like it should be working. Maybe force `$isConfirmNeeded` to be `true`